# form not display on html, django

Tags: python, html, django, web

I tried to make a blog that allows user posts, store the posts in the db along with the posted date time and the person who posted it.

My problem is that I somehow cannot load the {{form}} to my UI, which makes my form invalid and I just don't know why it doesn't show up the input text box. 
[image: UI]

I'm not sure if I need a get_post function, but I'll just put it in views.py. (I havnt write the html of that part yet. Just need to see the form first.)
I'm pretty new to Django, can somebody pls help me with this!!!  Thanks!

Below are my files.

blog.html file:

```
{% block posts %}
<div>
<span>New Post: </span>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'posts' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{form}}
                <!--not showing in UI-->
            </table>
            <input id="id_post_button" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>
<div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('posts', views.post_action, name='posts'),
    path('post/<int:id>', views.get_post, name='post'),
]
```

Models.py

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    post_input_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_profile = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    post_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'id=' + str(self.user_id) + ", post_date_time=" + self.post_date_time + ", post_input_text=" + self.post_input_text + ", post_profile=" + self.post_profile
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def post_action(request):
    print("----post action---")
    context = {}
    if request.method == "GET":
        context['form'] = CreatePost()
        context['posts']= PostModel.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)
        return render(request, "socialnetwork/blog.html", context)

    form = CreatePost(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if not form.is_valid():
        print("not valid ~~~~~~~~")
        context['form'] = form
        context['posts'] = PostModel.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)
        return render(request, "socialnetwork/blog.html", context)

    post_input_text = form.cleaned_data.get("post_input_text")
    post_date_time = form.cleaned_data.get("post_date_time")
    post_profile = form.cleaned_data.get("post_profile")
    obj = PostModel.objects.get(
        user_id = request.user.id,
    )
    obj.post_input_text = form.cleaned_data.get("post_input_text")
    obj.post_date_time = form.cleaned_data.get("post_date_time")
    obj.post_profile = form.cleaned_data.get("post_profile")
    obj.save()
    form = CreatePost() #refresh the form to original state

    context['form'] = form
    context['posts'] = obj
    return render(request, "socialnetwork/blog.html", context)


def get_post(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(PostModel, id=id)
    print('Picture #{} fetched from db: {} (type={})'.format(id, item.post_input_text, item.post_profile, item.post_date_time))
    if not item.post_input_text:
        raise Http404
    return HttpResponse(item.post_input_text)
```

forms.py

```
class CreatePost(forms.Form):
    post_input_text = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_profile = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    post_date_time = forms.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Open your browser's inspector - or use curl or whatever to get the response contents - and check the html.

Comment: does `{{ form.as_p }}` work?

Comment: No, I don't know why... can't find what I lost

Answer (score 0):

Update the template with `{{ form.as_table }}`, instead of `{{form}}`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work by changing it to {{ form.as_table }}